# HTTP status codes - Backbone.js and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, backbone.js, get

Backbone.js has a neat feature where you are able to sync changes back to your sever using standard HTTP verbs.

For example you may have a model object and some code which executes a get:

```
var coolModel = Backbone.Model.extend({url:'mysite/mymodel'});
var myCoolModel = new coolModel();
myCoolModel.fetch({error:processError});
```

Under the case where the server returns a 4XX or 5XX the error function 'processError' is run, which is great, you are able to process the error in which ever way suits.

As backbone.js uses jQuery to perform the GET, Jquery reports the  error, which it is. The 4XX is a valid error which should be recovered from, my client side app is not broken, it just needs to behave slightly differently.

My question is - is it considered bad practice to have this error raised from jQuery displayed in the browsers console window or status bar? Should I be suppressing this error somehow so that users in production don't see an error reported by the browser when the error is recoverable? Or is it correct in the land of HTTP to leave it as is?

Comment: If you have model validation in place and your server side script works correctly than you should not see these errors. In any case, if user did not cause these errors by wrong input etc, don't show them to the user.

Comment: Does jQuery really report errors to the console? Or do you mean the network panel of your browser's debugging tool, where the status codes can be seen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling errors in Backbone is a really interesting topic and one I hope to write about at some point.  It's very nice to visually indicate errors to your users in a non-obtrusive manner.  Some things to consider are:

- Your users are not looking at the status bar or developer tools
- Your users are expecting specific behavior from your application
- When your application does not behave correctly visual problem indicators are important

I'd recommend considering how the failure impacts the user's intention.  For instance if they are fetching data for the first page and that data is not returned correctly, you will need to handle the error by displaying a failure of data retrieved (or even better fall back on previously loaded data from a cache... it it exists).  If the intention is to save an item and the error code returned is 400 that is definitely not a success and should be indicated that the user should retry saving again, (or perhaps attempt a re-save on an interval).

You can silently ignore errors and not indicate them, but your users will get confused and it will lead to unexpected problems.  I can't preach to use perfect error handling, because I'm still getting better at it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I would say HTTP status codes are there for a reason, entirely valid if the reason for them is valid, so yes, just use them. *However*: `400` means `Bad Request`, which means the input is syntactically *wrong*. You *should* send a more [appropriate header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) (like `409` for a conflict, `428` for a failed precondition, etc.). I'm struggling to come up with a project with a valid use for `418 I'm a teapot`, but I will succeed some day..

Anybody interested in the inner workings of your site could look at the console, but there should be no problem with this, nor should you overly pander to a clean look there, just make sure your own process flow is sound.

Comment: Thanks for this. I might not have been clear. I will amend my question. I'm comfortable that using status codes is the way to go, and its not really a question of which status code to use. My question is is it appropriate to suppress this error so that users in production don't see an error reported by the browser when the error is recoverable.

Comment: 'normal' users will not see any error.. People with the console 'open' are not normal users. It would be like you being a taxi-driver, and  your clients popping open the hood of your car to asses your engine: doesn't happen really. Or am I still missing the point somewhere?